# Kendo Angular 2 Grid Filter similar to Excel

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

How can We implement an excel-like filtering on a grid using kendo-angular. I can't find a solution in the documentation.

This is the feature in JQuery version:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/spreadsheet/sorting-filtering

edit 1: a filter similar to this one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
   <ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter let-column="column">
     <kendo-grid-string-filter-cell
       [showOperators]="false"
       [column]="column"
       [filter]="filter">
     </kendo-grid-string-filter-cell>
   </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/built-in-template/

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question. I need set filters to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: (In Filter Menu option inside it. Follow second-last example)

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/reusable-filter/

Small change in it. There 'multicheck-filter.component.ts' file will give you this error:

Property 'value' does not exist on type 'FilterDescriptor | CompositeFilterDescriptor'.
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'CompositeFilterDescriptor'.

To resolve it, you need to replace below given code inside ngAfterViewInit()

this.value = this.currentFilter.filters.map(FilterDescriptor => f.value);

With below given code.

this.value = this.currentFilter.filters.map((f:FilterDescriptor) => f.value);

and also import 'FilterDescriptor' from '@progress/kendo-data-query'.